# External disk fatal hardware error

Tags: partitioning, external-hard-drive, data-recovery, hard-drive-recovery

I am trying to get access to my external hard drive and hopefully the data on it. However, my disk is not being recognized by the computer. I have tried opening Windows disk manager and it immediately gives me the pop-up window, that I have to Initialize the disk with ( MBR or GPT tables) if I want to use the disk, but when I click ok, it gives me the error: **The request failed due to a fatal device hardware error**, in disk part, it is being recognized but with the size of 0 bytes. I had used TestDisk program but the disk is not being recognized.

Are there any other steps I can try for recovering data?

Answer (score 0):

Questions: Does the disk react when power is turned on? Is the disk self-powered
or getting its power from the computer? Is it a new disk?

In any case, your options are limited and some may not be possible or easy:

- Try the disk on another port or computer
- Try another cable of good quality
- Extract the disk from the enclosure and put it either as an internal disk
  inside the computer or inside another enclosure.
- If nothing succeeds, a professional might be able to do more.

Comment: yes, I have tried all of it. It is around 4 years old Western Digitals disk. When I plug the disk into the computer, it starts to make sounds, just a bit noisier than usual but just for the first 10-15 seconds then it quiets down to normal, but at least it is running.

Comment: A disk shouldn't be noisy, unless the head is scratching the disk. This is bad news. Sorry, but I don't believe this is fixable.